# I create app in flutter text to speech and save it in storage

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to create flutter app which speak my text and also save it into the storage. below is my
code when I add tts package and path_provider then it show me this error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  @override
  final _textController = TextEditingController();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Input Page'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _textController,
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Add code to perform speech here
                },
                child: Text('Speak'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Add code to save data here
                },
                child: Text('Save'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**it show me this error**
Flutter Fix

│ The plugin flutter_tts requires a higher Android SDK version.
│
│ Fix this issue by adding the following to the file C:\flutter all project\3\master flutter
│
│ course\delete this file\flutter_application_1\android\app\build.gradle:
│
│ android {
│
│   defaultConfig {
│
│     minSdkVersion 21

```
                                                                   │
```

│   }
│
│ }
│
│                                                                                               │
│ Note that your app won't be available to users running Android SDKs below 21.

Alternatively, try to find a version of this plugin that supports these lower versions of the
│
│ Android SDK.
│
│ For more information, see:
│
│ https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration
│

Comment: sir, i am new to flutter so i Just want to find where this minsdkversion in VS Code. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **android/app/build.gradle** file of your project and change you minSdkVersion to 21.

```
defaultConfig {
    //...
    minSdkVersion 21
    //...
}
```

Comment: vikram I am using VS code is the procedure count for VS code . I cannot find this minsdkversion in VS Code

Comment: thank you sir i solved it don't forget to vote my question

Comment: most welcome.
Do follow me on linkedin and in youtube @gowithflutter